# Constraint propagation using Projection rule

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming

I've found this example of constraint propagation using projection rule
[image]
We have

```
C = { x1 ≠ x2, x1 ≥ x2 }

< C; x1 ∈ {1,2,3}, x2 ∈ {1,2,3} >
```

They say that applying propagation rule, does not give any simplification.

**I'm not sure why this is the case. Shouldn't we get?**

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2,3}, x2 ∈ {1,2} >
```

Other steps in the example, make sense that to me, e.g.

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2}, x2 ∈ {1,2,3} >
```

produces

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2}, x2 ∈ {1} >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the constraint in your example is `x1 >= x2`, and not `x1 > x2`.

Given that the iniital domains are `{1,2,3}` for both variables, neither `x1 >= x2` nor `x1 != x2` can be used to draw any conclusions.